# dynamically created input fields are not recognized

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, please help with me. I have a form for entering destination(s). the minimum number of destinations is 1 and there is no limit for maximum.

**Order component: (parent)**

```
import { ViewChild, Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { DestinationsComponent } from '../destinations/destinations.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html'
})

addNextDestination(){
  this.nextDestinationId++;
  this.focusedDestination = (this.nextDestinationId + 1);
  let index = this.nextDestinationId;
  let nextDestinationArr = {
    'nextDestinationId': index,
    'nextDestinationLat': '',
    'nextDestinationLng': '',
  };
  this.nextDestinations[index] = nextDestinationArr;
}
```

**Address template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let nextDestination of nextDestinations | slice:1; let $destNum=index;">
  <destinations #destComponent
    [destNum]="$destNum"
    [focusedDestination] = "focusedDestination"
    [nextDestination]="nextDestination"
    (postConfirmNextDestination)="confirmNextDestination($event)">
  </destinations>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <label (click)="addNextDestination()" style="color: blue; cursor: pointer; font-size: 18px;"><fa name="map-marker"></fa> Add Destination </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Destinations Component: (child)**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'destinations',
  templateUrl: './destinations.component.html'
})

export class DestinationsComponent{

  @Input() nextDestination: any[];
  @Input() destNum: number;
  @Input() focusedDestination: number;

  @Output() postConfirmNextDestination = new EventEmitter<string>();

  nextDestinationLat: any[] = {};
  nextDestinationLng: any[] = {};

  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {
  }

  locateNextDestination(){

    this.nextDestination.nextDestinationLat = this.nextDestinationLat[this.focusedDestination];
    this.nextDestination.nextDestinationLng = this.nextDestinationLng[this.focusedDestination];

    //this.postConfirmNextDestination.next();
  }
}
```

**Destinations Template:**

```
<div class="row box-body">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <label><fa name="map-marker"></fa>Destinatino Number: {{destNum}} </label>
  </div>

    <input type="text" name="nextDestinationLat{{destNum}}" [(ngModel)]="nextDestinationLat[destNum]" />
    <input type="text" name="nextDestinationLng{{destNum}}" [(ngModel)]="nextDestinationLng[destNum]" />

  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

I am using googlemaps api to select points on map as destination, I can insert the destination details for the first time that the destination template is instanced. But I do not have access to the next dynamically added template's inputs. Its like the new dynamic input elements are not detected at all. Please help me with the issue. sorry for my english. i will explain more if not understtandable above.

Comment: any comments yet?

Comment: you can manually trigger the change detection using `ChangeDetectorRef `
 `this.ref.detectChanges();`.
Please elaborate your problem if my understanding is not correct.